# How to call the c library from assembly code on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, linker

I'm trying to compile a little program in Linux assembly on Intel architecture. I want to use some functions of the C library, but it doesn't link.

Here is my assembly program :

```
.text
.globl main

main:
    pushl $512
    call malloc
    addl $4, %esp

    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

I'm compiling with

```
as --32 -o output.o output.asm
```

here, everything goes fine. And then when i'm linking with

```
ld -static -m elf_i386 -o a.out output.o -lc
```

, I got these errors :

> (.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
>   /usr/lib32/libc.a(iofclose.o):(.eh_frame+0x167): undefined reference
>   to`__gcc_personality_v0' /usr/lib32/libc.a(iofflush.o): In function
>   `fflush': (.text+0xd7): undefined reference to`_Unwind_Resume'
>   /usr/lib32/libc.a(iofflush.o):(.eh_frame+0xdf): undefined reference to
>   `__gcc_personality_v0' /usr/lib32/libc.a(iofputs.o): In function`
>   fputs': (.text+0x108): undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
>   /usr/lib32/libc.a(iofputs.o):(.eh_frame+0xdf): undefined reference to`
>   __gcc_personality_v0' /usr/lib32/libc.a(iofwrite.o): In function
>   `fwrite':

(I've another errors, but it is enough to see the problem, I think)

I saw some solutions indicating that I should link with -lgcc but on my computer the library is not found...

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Try linking with gcc instead of ld

Answer (score 5, accepted):

glibc requires certain initialization code to be statically linked with the executable. The easiest way to do this is to link using gcc:

```
gcc -static -o a.out output.o
```

You can see exactly what is being linked in by passing `-v` to `gcc` as well.

Comment: It works well. Thank you :) I just added the -m32 option in order to compile on my 64 bit machine, but that's great.

Answer (score 4):

I've had same issue, so I did

```
# gcc -static -o a.out hello.o -v
```

which gave me information about what to include, then I could link using ld:

```
# ld -static -o hello -L`gcc -print-file-name=` /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o hello.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.7/crtbeginT.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.7/crtend.o --start-group -lc -lgcc -lgcc_eh --end-group
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually let gcc do the thing instead of using directly ld. Once you have the object, just `gcc object.o -o executable`